# How to make plt.savefig() save image for 'maximized' window instead of default size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I know that this question have been raised previously but it didnt solve the problem. I am trying to plot graphs using subplots my problem is same as the question with similar title. I think instead of explaining in words I will show you what is happening and what I want. the first image is the plot I get when I run the code[image]

everything here is superimposed over each other but when i maximize the image the result is good[image]

In this new image everything looks good. I want to save the plots directly as .pdf instead of showing them on screen and manually maximizing and then saving it.
I tried

```
plt.savefig('plot.pdf')
```

but it saves the bad quality, same as the top image as pdf but I want the clean plots like the lower one. I have to make hundreds of these plots so I have to save them automatically. I dont know what backends are and how they work cause i am new in python I saw my posts related to this which had backends I tried but they didnt worked for me giving me an error everytime. How this is possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: You can set the figure size explicitly using e.g. `plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))`

Comment: Yeah that worked with few changes in re-positioning the text and few other things.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the scaling of each plot or the figure size: 
**For scaling:**
You can try and change the axes scaling by:

```
plt.axis([40, 160, 0.01, 0.1])
```

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) you can find a nice tutorial for `matplotlib`.
**For figure:**
Read [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) first, and then try to change some parameters values and see if it help, for example:

```
figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
```

Anyway, I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

this worked form me, first you set the window size in inches an then in plot funcion you adjust the size with the dpi option, here it sets the figure in 1080x1920 resolution

```
fig.set_size_inches(19.20, 10.80)
plt.savefig(dest,bbox_inches='tight',format="svg",dpi=100,orientation="landscape")
```